# LoadError (cannot load such file -- bcrypt)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-2.3

Is anyone facing this issue:

`LoadError (cannot load such file -- bcrypt)`

in a Rails 5 application ?

My model is like that:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
      has_secure_password
end
```

I have bundle installed bcrypt (which is in my Gemfile). I'm able to require it in irb, but my rails application is getting this error.

I'm using Mac OS X Sierra and Ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: Did you try restarting your server after `bundle install`?

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace?

Comment: I was using docker to runthe application. Apparently I was able to solve it when I destroyed the container and created again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error and restarted the server to get it to work like Black Enigma said. i.e. after running `bundle install` in the terminal, exit out of the server you're running on then run `rails server` again.
Works fine now.